# How to enable notification number badge style on my android app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

In mobile notification settings, all apps have the ability to show notification badge in dot style, but only some apps that supports to show it in numbers style, are you have any idea how to make my app programmatically support both styles not only dot one with android Kotlin?

[image: mobile screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Showing numbers as a badge on a launcher icon is not a feature of Android. That is either added by your device manufacturer or by your launcher developer. You will need to find out and then research them to see what options they have for letting third-party apps contribute number badges.